# Python List Comprehension that looks at each mentee's previous mentors they have already met with and assigns mentor they have NEVER met with

Tags: python, csv, list-comprehension

So I have already written the first portion which matches Mentees with Mentors randomly every time the code is run, with no duplicates ever. This matches are created by using a mentee.csv (list of mentees)(string) & mentors.csv(list of mentors)(string). Then outputs the final list into FinalList.csv.

I want to add in the ability to read off of a 3rd csv file named previousmentormatches.csv. This will include the previous mentors (each mentee meet once a month with different mentor) that EACH mentee has matched with. Some mentees have been in the committee for longer, so they have matched with more mentors.

I am struggling with finding the best / easiest way to do this. I was thinking about using some sort of Dict List Comprehension. I also want to use the 3rd csv file instead of hardcoding the previous mentee-->mentor matches into EACH mentee. (Also if this could be achieved using pandas dataframes that would be ideal, but not required.) Here is the code.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime

#Setting data&time variable
date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')

#the 2 required lists that the data is getting pulled from
list1 = list(csv.reader(open('data/mentees.csv')))
list2 = list(csv.reader(open('data/mentors.csv')))

header1, header2 = list1.pop(0), list2.pop(0)
random.shuffle(list1)
random.shuffle(list2)
list1 = [header1]+list1
list2 = [header2]+list2
FinalMatch = [list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]

#printing the contents of the final match calculations for debugging purposes
print(FinalMatch)

#storing into datadrame and writing to csv / excel file
df = pd.DataFrame(FinalMatch)
df.to_csv(f'FinalMatch{date}.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

OUTPUT:

| MENTEES | MENTORS |
| --- | --- |
| `John Smith <menteeemail1@.com>` | `MentorName#1 <mentoremail1@.com>` |
| `Joe Smoe <menteeemail1@.com>` | `MentorName#2 <mentoremail2@.com>` |
| `Johnny Walker <menteeemail1@.com>` | `MentorName#3 <mentoremail3@.com>` |

The purpose of this program is to assign mentees with mentors they have never met with and take into account the past mentors each mentee has already met with in the past (once per month). So when the code is run and the matches are made, I need to make sure that the mentee has a completely new mentor they have NEVER met with. It would be different for each mentee as each mentee has met with different mentors through out the year.

Thankyou for any help!!

UPDATE: My prev_mentors.csv looks like this:

| mentees, | prev_mentors |
| --- | --- |
| `Joe Smoe,` | `"['prevmentor1', 'prevmentor2', 'prevmentor3', 'prevmentor4', 'prevmentor5', 'prevmentor6', 'prevmentor7', 'prevmentor8', 'prevmentor9', 'prevmentor10']"` |
| `Johhny B,` | `"['prevmentor1', 'prevmentor2', 'prevmentor3', 'prevmentor4', 'prevmentor5', 'prevmentor6', 'prevmentor7']"` |
| `Aaron B,` | `"['prevmentor1', 'prevmentor2', 'prevmentor3', 'prevmentor4']"` |

Comment: Thankyou so much @Seth! Appreciate the table fix!!

Comment: no problem Kakkarot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
this function should read colA as the mentee, and each column after as a prev mentor and 
populate the mentees array with {"mentee":"","prev_mentors":[]}
mentees = []
with open("prev_mentors.csv","r") as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        temp = line.split(",")
        mentees.append({"mentee":temp[0]})
        for x in temp[1:]
            mentees[len(mentees)]['prev_mentors'].append(x)
        line = file.readline()
"""

import random
mentees = [{"mentee":"john","mentor":"","prev_mentors":["jane c.","mark m."]}]
mentors = ["jane c.","mark m.","cindy y."]
random.shuffle(mentors)
for mentee in mentees:
    for idx,mentor in enumerate(mentors):
        if mentor not in mentee['prev_mentors']:
            mentee['mentor'] = mentors.pop(idx)
            break
print(mentees)
```

i think something like this might work for you?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I really wanted to avoid going through EACH mentee as there's about 36 mentees and 50 mentors. And EACH mentee has met with a different mentor and different # of mentors. So i couldnt do ```mentees = [{ }]``` It would have to end up being ```mentee1 = [{ }], mentee2 = [{ }]``` all the way until mentee36 and that wouldn't be practical. The only STATIC thing are the mentors in mentors.csv, and the mentees in mentees.csv. The only thing thats unique, are the mentors EACH mentee has previously matched up with (previousmentormatches.csv)

Comment: im confused on what you mean by needing to make mentee1, mentee2? you would just append them to the mentees list.  mentee1 = {"mentee":"jon","mentor":"unknown","prev_mentors":[array of prev mentors]} instead of mentee1=[{}]

Comment: no yea I juts didnt feel like putting in the data in my comment.....lol I actually tried it out and it does work to some extent. This is what i changed it too to test: ```mentee1 = [{"mentee":"Jeremy","mentor":"","prev_mentors":["jane c.","Tim n.","Howard d.","Steven s."]}]``` ... and the mentee2 and so on...all the way to 36. I also put in an FOR loops for EACH new mentee. BUT I always gives the same values though once its ran once. Is there a good way to make it more random so it changes everytime you run it but still takes into account the previous mentors? Thanks this is super helpful!

Comment: i think randomly shuffling the mentors list would make it change each time it's run, ill edit my answer

Comment: I also really wanted to do this using the 3 .csv files: (mentees.csv, mentors.csv, and previousmatches.csv) but I guess I could tweak this code to somehow do that.

Comment: yeah, honestly i dont think you need 3.  just have a static list of mentors.  and have all mentees on colA and prev mentors on B,C,D....  let me add some more code up to my answer

Comment: i getting this error:  File "mentormatching.py", line 38, in <module>
    mentees[len(mentees)]['prev_mentors'].append(x)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range, try  mentees[len(mentees)-1]

Comment: After adding the -1, I just get KeyError: 'prev_mentors' and i tried everything to fix. Yes in my prev_mentors.csv the 2nd column is 100% spelt correct (prev_mentors) ughhhh i hate this, im about to just give up for the day lol *I added the prev_mentors.csv to my example up above for you to take a look*